# Extjs 5.1 combobox expands ubnormally in internet explorer 11

Tags: extjs, extjs5

When i set a selection in a combobox `combo.select(myselection)`
or when i bind the selection to the combobox with the use of the view model
`viewmodel.setData(...)`, then automatically the combobox expands.

This happens randomly to some comboxes in the form, others behave normally and appears only in Internet Explorer (I use version 11). Chrome, firefox ,opera, dolphin behaves normally. 
In the debug console I don't see this, strange.Has anybody faced the same problem? Is it a bug of ext?

Comment: Hi, do you think you could provide a fiddle with your issue (https://fiddle.sencha.com) I was unable to reproduce this BUG

Comment: I ran into this same bug in IE11 when using a viewModel to bind data to a combo. The issue is that doQuery calls expand and in only IE11 this results in the combo expanding on combo.setValue(). I can reproduce this by calling setValue as well as by using the viewModel.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ma0

Answer (score 0):

Solution you can find here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053309/combobox-in-ie-10-11-be-focus
```

Problem is fixed in newer verion